# WPF Animation on MouseDown and do the changes back on MouseUp

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to make a little animation when the user clicks.
So I set up the following style and set it on my grid - but the MouseUp Animation doesn't work.

```
<Style x:Key="AnimatedButton" TargetType="Grid">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.1" From="1.0" To="0.8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseUp">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.1" From="0.8" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: works for me too!

Comment: Any idea? It's not working on my site.

Comment: These Grids are hosted in a Grid where Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled="False"

Comment: How can I debug such a behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was hard!
The styled Grid is part of a UserControl.

Now this UserControl is capturing the mouse on MouseDown and release the capture on MouseUp. So the captured MouseUp is going to the UserControl. But the style was definied for the underlying Grid. Due to the capture the Grid never gets the MouseUp.

So I changed the TargetType of the Style to "UserControl" and set the UserControl.Style to this instead of a styled grid and all is working.